# OpenERP Report Design in applications OpenOffice Writer

Tags: report, odoo

If anyone could give a tutorial how to design report related modules with other modules using `OpenERP Report Design` in applications `OpenOffice Writer`?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the below link to learn the Open Office Report (RML Report)**
**for OpenERP 7.0**

[Reference 1](https://doc.odoo.com/6.1/developer/05_reports/)

[Reference 2](https://doc.odoo.com/6.0/developer/3_11_reports/11_2_XSL-RML_reports/)

[Reference 3](http://blog.openerp4you.in/2013/06/how-to-create-report-in-openerp-using.html)

[Reference 4](https://colinnewell.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/adding-new-reports-to-openerp/)

[Reference 5](http://sahotaparamjitsingh.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-create-reports-in-openerp.html)

[RML USER GUIDE 1](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml2pdf-userguide.pdf)

[RML USER GUIDE 2](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml-for-idiots.pdf)

I hope this should helpful for you ..!!:)